# show/hide password text using Nativescript via eye icon

Tags: nativescript

I want to add the eye-kind of icon to the Password text field.
On clicking that icon it should show the password or hide the password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `(tap)` event on the icon, then toggle the `secure` property on the `TextField` in that handler.

Another option is to use a property in your code behind like `shouldSeePassword` then bind `[secure]=shouldSeePassword` for the `TextField`. Then your `(tap)` event would toggle `shouldSeePassword` between `true` and `false` which will show/hide the text in the `TextField`.

To put the icon in the `TextField` you can use a `GridLayout` like this:

```
<GridLayout columns='*,auto' rows='auto'>
    <TextField col='0' row='0'></TextField>
    <Label col='1' row='0' text='icon'></Label>
</GridLayout>
```

Comment: I want to add the icon in the text field itself.
PS: [link](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-rich-textfield/)